# convert date to midnight in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I want to truncate a specific date to midnight time in hive.
I have tried the following below, but it puts 12 hour time instead of 00.

```
date_format(MIN(date_and_time), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000')
```

Result obtained

```
2021-11-03 12:00:00.000
```

Any suggestions on that?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use `00:00:00` instead of `hh:00:00`?

Comment: yes I have corrected it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `HH` for a 24-hour clock:

```
date_format(MIN(date_and_time), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.000')
```